# Фильтры валидации в Yii

Tags: php, yii, фильтры

```
    array('message_text','filter','filter'=>'htmlspecialchars'),
```

Мне нужно прогнать текст, через htmlspecialchars, но только 1 раз. Тоесть, что бы htmlspecialchars_decode, смогло восстановить все теги.

Мой фильтр, работает но конвентирует строку типа:

```
<p>Текст</p>
```

В

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Текст&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

Такое ощущение, что он ее прогнал дважды. Подскажите пожалуйста, как прогнать через фильтр 1 раз, что бы на выходе было:

```
&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фильтр выполняется один раз для одного поля за одни вызов `validate()`. Если `validate()` вызвать несколько раз, то и фильтр также отработает несколько раз. Например, `save()` без параметров неявно вызывает `validate()`.

Именно по этой причине экранировать html в фильтре - не самое лучшее решение. Такую обработку обычно делают при выводе во view, c помощью CHtml::encode().

Comment: Это для записи в базу. Большое спасибо. Я просто экранирую пост данные